# Xcode 10 app upload on “negotiating connection…”

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect

I try to app upload but I waited 2 hours on this screen.And I finally got the app store connection error.Error messages is **"appstore connect unable to process the request. please try again or use a different transport(1360)"**. What should I do ??

Comment: i'm new in iOS sorry for that

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that blocks ports 33001 or 44001 outbound?  These ports must be open outbound to Apple to deliver an app.

Answer (score 1):

It's a network problem. Try again or use another ISP.

Comment: Seems does not resole the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is a problem with xcode 11. I used "Transporter" to upload my file as it says in this [link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123649)

1. Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.
2. From Xcode's organizer, select your archive and press "Distribute App"
3. Instead of "Upload", select "Export" and proceed as usual.
4. Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press "Deliver".

Credits to CrewNerd

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Answer (score 0):

None of the answers above worked for me, but found solution in this thread worked https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123649 .

Quoting the instruction that worked:

> Go to Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies and make sure "Auto Proxy Discovery" and "Automatic Proxy Configuration" are checked but none of the other proxy options are checked.

Here, Preferences is the "System Preferences" of MacOS.